# Does the linux subsystem in windows also run when no one is logged in?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get comfortable with hosting software on linux instead of windows. To try that, i want to use a linux system that runs on a windows machine. First, there is HyperV, from which i know will execute the linux VM in the background, even thou no one is logged in. Then there is the "Linux subsystem for windows".

Does the linux subsystem for windows run as a service, or does it need me to be logged in to provide services like webservers?

Comment: Take a look at : https://superuser.com/a/1344181/1127143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed the Ubuntu app on my PC. When I install it, it seems that the parent process ID is the one from Windows Explorer, so I don't think there's any service related to this.